# Loop with array inside subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran90, subroutine

i have a question about a loop inside a subroutine in fortran.

If i put this as subroutine, then i expect that the variable test becomes an array from 1 to 5.

p.s. `type3` is defined as `real, dimension(5,1)`

```
subroutine build(test)
    type(typelist)     :: test
    do i = 1, 5
        test%type3(i)         = i 
end subroutine build
```

However this gives an error ;

```
    ||Error: Rank mismatch in array reference  (1/2)|
```

And when i remove the "(i)" after test%type3, it will work, but the result is 5.000 5.000 5.000 5.000 5.000. So it only assigns the value from the last loop to all entries in the array.
And if i remove the %test the program does not know what type the variable test is anymore and it gives

```
 ||Error: Unclassifiable statement  |
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a tag for Fortran 90. You should make sure you use it in the future (and you don't need to mention language in the title).

Comment: This is an array rank broadcasting thing.  `type3 = i` will set all array elements equal to i, which is why you get all 5s (the last do loop iteration overwrites previous ones).  You can omit _all_ array indices this way.  But you can't just omit some (like one in a rank-2 array).  You could do `test%type3(i,:) = i` (to broadcast over the last index) or `test%type3(i,1) = i`, but you can't just omit array indices - in general, there's no way to tell which ones you're leaving out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to assign with `test%type3(i,1) = i`?

Since `type3` is a 2D array, you need two indices to assign values. When you type `test%type3 = i` you are assigning *all* elements at the same time with the same value. That is why in the end you get all `5.0`.

PS. Where is the `ENDDO` statement?

Comment: oh wow, that was it. I only had to turn the (i) into (i,1).
Thanks a lot

(and the end do statement was accidently fallen off when i removed all the pieces of code that were not relevant for this  question)